# How to create dropdown dependencies

Tags: python, html, django, dropdown

I have a dropdown taking distinct values from a database. Depending on the selected value in this dropdown, I want a second dropdown to be updated with other distinct values from the same table. As an example, let's say that I have a table with 'Continents' and 'Countries' fields, if I select 'Europe' for instance, I want the second dropdown to show the countries in my db which belong to this continent.

I managed to create the first dropdown and connect it to the db, but I'm struggling with the second step, which is to retrieve the first dropdown's selection and use it to update the second one.

Here is my views.py:

```
def MyView(request):

    query_results = data_world.objects.all()
    continents_list = ContinentsChoiceField()
    countries_list = CountriesChoiceField() 

    query_results_dict = {
        'query_results': query_results,
        'continents_list': continents_list ,
        'countries_list': countries_list ,
    }

    return render(request,'home.html', query_results_dict)
```

models.py:

```
class data_world(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    continent_name= models.TextField(db_column='CONTINENTS', blank=True, null=True)  
    country_name = models.TextField(db_column='COUNTRIES', blank=True, null=True) 
    city_name = models.TextField(db_column='CITIES', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'world'
```

forms.py:

```
class ContinentsChoiceField(forms.Form):

    continents = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=data_world.objects.values_list("continent_name", flat=True).distinct(),
        empty_label=None
    )

class CountriesChoiceField(forms.Form):

    countries = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=data_world.objects.values_list("country_name", flat=True).distinct(),
        empty_label=None
    )
```

home.html:

```
<select id="continents">
    {% for item in continents_list %}
    <option val="{{ item.continent_name }}"> {{ item }} </option>    
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedText(){
      var ct = document.getElementById("continents");
      var result_ct = ct.options[ct.selectedIndex].text;

      document.getElementById("result_ct").innerHTML = result_ct;
      }
  </script>

<button type="button" onclick="GetSelectedText()">Get Selected Value</button>

<select id="countries">
  {% for item in countries_list %}
  <option val="{{ item.country_name }}"> {{ item }} </option>    
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Edit 1: updated my html page with some Js code which helps me to retrieve the chosen continent. Now I would need to use it to display the corresponding countries in the second dropdown.

Comment: You either need to A) use JavaScript to recognise the change in dropdown 1 and request the items for the second or B) submit the page when the first choice has been made and put some code in your Django view to populate the second.  There are other questions on S.O. about how to submit the page when selecting a dropdown item.

Comment: I would prefer the JavaScript option, but don't know the language. Could any one help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The django-select2 package does exactly this.

Take a look at https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra.html

In models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class City(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', related_name="cities")
```

Then customise a form:

```
...
from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2Widget
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Country.objects.all(),
        label=u"Country",
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=Country,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
        )
)

city = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=City.objects.all(),
    label=u"City",
    widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
        model=City,
        search_fields=['name__icontains'],
        dependent_fields={'country': 'country'},
        max_results=500,
    )
)
```